# IOS Game Center: How to know when default sign in form for game center is finished?

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I was wondering how to know when Game Center sign in form is finished by the user. I am doing Facebook sign in automatically but I need to wait for Game Center login to finish. Is there any way of knowing that?

```
-(void) authenticateLocalPlayer {

    GKLocalPlayer* localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
    ^(UIViewController *viewController,
      NSError *error) {

        [self setLastError:error];

        if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = YES;
            NSLog(@"local Player Info: %@",localPlayer);
            [[UserManager sharedInstance] setGameCenterId:localPlayer.playerID];
            [[UserManager sharedInstance] setUserName:localPlayer.alias];
            [self retrieveFriends];
        } else if(viewController) {

            [self presentViewController:viewController];
        } else {
            _gameCenterFeaturesEnabled = NO;
        }
    };
}
-(void) setLastError:(NSError*)error {
    _lastError = [error copy];
    if (_lastError) {
        NSLog(@"GameKitHelper ERROR: %@", [[_lastError userInfo]
                                           description]);
    }
}
-(UIViewController*) getRootViewController {
    return [UIApplication
            sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
}

-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {
    UIViewController* rootVC = [self getRootViewController];
    [rootVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quote from `authenticateHandler` documentation

> The authenticate handler will be called whenever the authentication
>   process finishes or needs to show UI. The handler may be called
>   multiple times. Authentication will happen automatically when the
>   handler is first set and whenever the app returns to the foreground.
>   If the authentication process needs to display UI the viewController
>   property will be non-nil. Your application should present this view
>   controller and continue to wait for another call of the
>   authenticateHandler.  The view controller will be dismissed
>   automatically.
>
> Possible reasons for error:
>   1. Communications problem
>   2. User credentials invalid
>   3. User cancelled

So the block will be called multiple times,
For example if user is not logged in, a view-controller will be passed to this block, after you present it and user submits the form, he block will be executed once again.
Here is code that handles authentication:

```
- (void)authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    __weak typeof(localPlayer) weakLocalPlayer = localPlayer;
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler =
    ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error) {
            // Something happened, handle it...
            return;
        }
        __strong typeof(weakLocalPlayer) strongLocalPlayer = weakLocalPlayer;
        if (viewController) {
            // Just show it, user needs to submit the form
            return;
        }
        if (strongLocalPlayer.isAuthenticated) {
            // User completed login, do FB login
        } else {
            // GameKit is disabled, show guide to enable it
        }
    };
}
```